# what is the bset IDE and course or book for jakartaEE and spring?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, ide

I am new to spring5 and I saw that in order to learn spring well, first, it is better to learn a little JEE and become more familiar with its basics, so I have two questions:

1. First, what is the best idea for both spring and JakartaEE? Is it eclipse? Because I have seen many places that use eclipse, especially for JEE.
2. Secondly, what is the best book and the best course for spring and JEE? That is, separately for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First, what is the best IDE for both spring and JakartaEE?

Neither of these really require you to use a specific IDE so you can try out IntelliJ, VSCode, Netbeans and Eclipse to see what you like the best. If you're just starting out it might be best to use whatever is used by the instructor or in the book.

Eclipse has ton of plugins for pretty much everything java, but this comes at the cost of speed and stability along with complex albeit very configurable user interface. IntelliJ feels like Visual Studio but for Java with its more modern user interface, good default settings but isn't as configurable as eclipse and there's not as many plugins.

VSCode is great option if you're looking for something lighter and prefer doing things from command line or by fiddling with json, xml files. It's also great if you need to work with other languages. It's Java extensions are great but at the time of writing still a bit work in progress.

### best book and the best course for spring and JEE?

Probably best to focus on learning Spring and Spring Boot. This will make it easier to understand which parts of the Jakarta-EE are actually beneficial to learn.

I've liked the "in action" books from Manning Publications so might try out one of those. They've previews available for many of their books. So maybe check out most recent editions of Spring in Action and Spring boot in action. But like most books they might be a version or two behind but it's generally easier to catch up with the new version if you already know how to use the previous version.

For course you could check out Chad Darby's **Spring & Hibernate for Beginners (includes Spring Boot)** in Udemy. Haven't encountered many courses for Java-EE but there's **Java Enterprise Edition 8 for Beginners course** by Luqman Saeed but it's strictly focused on using Java-EE with application servers.